# What level of detail should be included in a CV when listing the courses assisted?

Tags: application, cv

I am a teaching/research assistant.

In my academic CV, I have a section called "Courses Assisted". I am not sure which way to go. I have <del>two</del> three different schemes on my mind:

First one, write all the semesters and list the courses assisted in that semester.

#### 2015 - 16 Fall

- AB 101 "An Introductory Course"
- CD 223 "An Advanced Course"

#### 2014 - 15 Summer

- CD 232 "A Hard Course"

#### 2014 - 15 Spring

- AB 101 "An Introductory Course"
- CD 232 "A Hard Course"

#### 2014 - 15 Fall

- AB 102 "Second Part of That Introductory Course"
- CD 223 "An Advanced Course"

and so on.

The second one, write the course names and then list all the semesters that I have assisted that course:

#### AB 101 "An Introductory Course"

- 2015-16 Fall
- 2014-15 Spring

#### AB 102 "Second Part of That Introductory Course"

- 2014-15 Fall

#### CD 223 "An Advanced Course"

- 2015-16 Fall
- 2014-15 Fall

#### CD 232 "A Hard Course"

- 2014-15 Summer
- 2014-15 Fall

and so on.

The third choice, I put a table like below:

[image]

Clearly, the last one contains much more information and takes much less space. But it is a little bit harder to read.

Even though the first and the second choices seem to take almost equal amount of space, the second one takes less when there are a lot of semesters and not so much courses.

The third one is not so ordinary and it takes a little bit more effort to read. But it contains almost all the information.

I am addressing the ones who are in hiring committee: Do you care about that much detail or do you only want to know which courses the applicant assisted? Is it worth to put that detail of level to reduce readability?

Or am I overthinking?

Comment: Nice season icons :)

Comment: @TomDworzanski Thanks! I've spent some time picking them :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've never been on a hiring committee, but I can tell you what's standard in my field (mathematics): something basically similar to your second option. I would probably put it in a more condensed format, for example:

**Courses Assisted**

- A Hard Course (Fall 2013)
- An Easy Course (Spring 2014, Fall 2014)
- and so on

No need to include course numbers (which mean nothing to anyone outside your university) or instructor names (even the most diligent hiring committee is unlikely to call professors you've taught under, beyond the teaching references you personally solicit).

Your third option (the table) is very hard to read, and includes a lot of information that the hiring committee is unlikely to need or care about.